# Renew EEA family permit

Tags: visas, uk

I am an EU national and my wife has non-EU nationality with a permanent residence card from the Netherlands. We both work in the Netherlands with permanent jobs.

We applied for her EEA family permit as we wanted to go for holidays to the UK in Aug. 18. Her EEA permit expires in Jan. 19 and we are planning to visit the UK again in Feb. 19 for 1-2 weeks. Can we apply for a new EEA permit before her previous EEA permit is expired?

For a UK tourist visa we need to wait for 6 months before we make a new application. Is this valid for an EEA family permit as well?

Comment: I googled overlapping EEA permits since this question is relevant for me too. A user on an expat forum said that it wasn't an issue; when his wife got a new EEA FP, the old one was cancelled (with a cancelled stamp on it).

Comment: thanks for your response. I will make an appointment and see how they respond.

Comment: Does your wife's card note that she is the family member of an EU citizen? If so, she does not need an EEA family permit.

Comment: unfortuantey its doesnt say anything like that. She had recently renewed her residence permit (permanent) but not sure why its not mentioned. May be its needed to request separately.

Comment: She probably has a national residence permit. The Article 10 card (stating she's a family member) is issued afaik by a different EU country (not the one you are the citizen of) if you both live there.

Comment: @GaneshKandge how did it go?

Answer (score 1):

No.  You do not have to wait.  There is no restriction on the length or frequency of visits with an EEA family permit, since it evidences the right of the bearer to enjoy freedom of movement in the United Kingdom.

In fact, there is no strict six-month waiting period for a standard visitor visa, either.  Consider the case of someone with a standard visitor visa valid from March 1st through the end of August.  The person spends one week in the UK in March and one week in July.  Then, after returning home in July, the person wants to plan a one-week trip for September, just days after the expiration of the visa.  There is nothing preventing this, nor is there anything preventing an application for a new visa being lodged in July.